Sentence casing using kotlin built-in function
I want to achieve Sentence casing in kotlin using kotlin built-in function
E.g Smooth Meter Readings to Smooth meter readings
capitalize appear depreciated, so using replaceFirstChar
Kotlin Capitalization

After applying the suggested approach Kotlin replaceFirstChar, still not working

Sample
fun main() {
        var sample = "Smooth Meter Readings"
    sample.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }
    println(sample)
}

What I want to achieve is even if the string is camel case, I want to use the kotlin built-in function to make only the first character upper case without writing extra logic for this
What am I doing wrong here.

How would the function know it should lower the "Readings", but it shouldn't lower the "GPS"?

GPS could also go lower,

I  have updated the sample, it is not about the gprs but achieving sentence casing

You use this "sentence casing" term a lot here, but please be aware there is no strict definition on what does it mean exactly. For this reason there are no builtin functions for it. If you simply mean to make the first letter uppercase and lower everything else, then you did this in your answer. Contrary to what you seem to think, capitalize wouldn't help you here, because similarly to replaceFirstChar, it wouldn't lower any chars. It simply makes the first letter uppercase.

what I meant by sentence casing is capitalize()... and since it is depreciated, replaceFirstChar is not working in a case of having a camel case string. the solution I later used was first converted everything to string then used replaceFirstChar

then I cam up with another question if we can have an optimize built in function that does this without having to convert the string to lower case

What makes you think capitalize does a different thing than replaceFirstChar? It is effectively the same as replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }. It doesn't lower anything. I think you fixed yourself into thinking you need an "optimized" solution for this. You say you don't want to lower the string, but this is exactly what you ask for: make the first letter uppercase and lower everything else. We can definitely write a function that does this in a single pass, without creating intermediary string, but I'm not convinced it is worth additional complexity.

capitalize() is depreciated, so I was using replaceFirstChar directly on string like string. replaceFirstChar but in it not giving only the first character capitalized so I end up having Smooth Meter Readings after using .replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }...

And you get exactly the same using capitalize(). Did you ever try to run it to check by yourself?

now I get what you are saying.. capitalize and replaceFirstChar are the same....  so how do I achieve only the first character upper case even if the string giving is camel case

I updated the question now... do you get it

Your code isnt working because Smooth GPS Readings is considered a single string by kotlin so there is no way to manipulate each word using capitalize or replaceFirstChar.

You will have to seperate each word first and manipulate them individually accordingly.
You gotta do somthing like this since there is no in-built way to do that:
fun main() {
  var sentence = "Use 24-Hour Format"
  var words = sentence.split(' ')

  var listOfWords = mutableListOf<String>()
  for (i in words.indices) {
    var word = words[i]
    listOfWords.add(
      // skips first word
      if (i == 0) word else word.lowercase()
      // or anything you want
    )
  }

  // concatenate the words
  sentence = listOfWords.joinToString(separator = " ")
  println(sentence)
}

Edit: From the docs
val sentence = "Welcome to kotlin!"
val words = sentence.split(' ');
println(words.joinToString(separator = " ") { word -> word.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() } }) //Welcome To Kotlin(Title Case)


Still not working ... try the sample code here https://play.kotlinlang.org/

I simply pointed out the bug you in your code. Now if you want to string into sentence case then you gotta specify explicitly what word should have capital first letter like 'GPS' in your case and what word should have small first letter like 'reading' in your case because your program dosent. Either you can convert all first letter to caps or all letter to small.

replaceFirstChar is doing exactly what is in its name - changing the very first character in the provided String. println("Smooth GPS Readings".replaceFirstChar { it.lowercase() }) will produce smooth GPS Readings - with the first character 'S' changed to lower case.

what I am asking is the kotlin built-in function to achieve sentence casing... the sample I pasted is for anyone to test....

could you update the code to achieve my intended result .. thanks

E.g Smooth GPS Readings to Smooth GPS readings in this example you want to convert Readings into readings right? because i will need more context

Yes..e.g Smooth GPS Readings to Smooth GPS readings, User
Use 24-Hour Format to Use 24-hour format.

why can't we use the kotlin-built in function..... following this guide https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/capitalize.html#kotlin.text$capitalize(kotlin.String,%20java.util.Locale)/locale

built-in function is already optimized

like i said Smooth GPS Readings contains white spaces for us it is combination of three  words but for kotlin it is a single string and capitalize will convert  smooth GPS Readingsto Smooth GPS Readings  only it will treat it as a single string.

Take a look at the latest edit and see it for your self abcd abcd.capitalize() prints Abcd abcd

ignore the sample case I gave, try  Coordinate Format to  Coordinate format. with the built-in kotlin function

Thanks for the answer but try and get my question... I want to use kotlin built-in function without extra logic for sentence casing.... e.g  Coordinate Format to Coordinate format.....

Nope dosent work. Coordinate Format stays unchanged. coordinate Format gets converted to Coordinate Format instead.

why can't I get it formated.. that is what I want to achieve... sentence casing

Thanks for the answer but try and get my question... I want to use kotlin built-in function without extra logic for sentence casing.... e.g Coordinate Format to Coordinate format.....  i dont know if you can do that with a string without seperating the words first.

Your code isnt working because Coordinate Format is considered a single string by kotlin so there is no way to manipulate each word using capitalize or replaceFirstChar. it returns a single value that is this Coordinate Format string and only manipulates C and not F beacuse Coordinate Format is a single value and Coordinate and Format are not two seperate values.

we have a built-in function that does this but now depreciated ... check the link in my question... adding extra logic can increase the time/space complexity.... looking at achieving this with the built-in function

Look at the edit code is from the link you provided.

I found a solution but not sure if it is the optimizes version

This could be vastly reduced to sentence.split(' ').mapIndexed { i, word -> if (i == 0) word else word.lowercase() }.joinToString(separator = " "), but it won't capitalize the first character of each sentence, it only capitalizes the first character of the string.

There are multiple confusing parts or misconceptions in this question. "Sentence casing" is a pretty vague term and no surprise there isn't a ready to use function for it. Also, capitalize doesn't do what is asked in the question - it makes the first letter uppercase, but it doesn't change anything in remaining chars.
From comments it seems the question is really to make the first letter uppercase and lower everything else. I would say the most reasonable solution is by lowering the string and making the first letter uppercase, because this is exactly what we need:
sample.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }

This solution is clear on its meaning to any reader and it is efficient. Thinking that the builtin function will be somehow faster, is another misconception. Whatever solution we choose, it will be effectively O(n). We can't get a better time complexity, no matter builtin or not.
If we don't like the idea we copy the string twice - first to lower, than to upper the first, we can do this in a single pass:
fun main() {
    println("Smooth Meter Readings".upperFirstOnly())
}

fun String.upperFirstOnly(): String {
    if (isEmpty()) return this
    val iter = iterator()
    return buildString(length) {
        append(iter.nextChar().uppercaseChar())
        iter.forEach { append(it.lowercaseChar()) }
    }
}

However, I'm not convinced it is worth the effort and additional complexity. It looks like a premature optimization to me.

Thank you  for this, I was able to think of this solution sample.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() } after my discussion with @armankhantech.. which fix my problem and efficient enough. then I was thinking without extra logic or the solution I provided above if there is any built-in function in kotlin that does this, thinking instead of my solution that I need to first convert all to lower case before making the first character capital letter.. I could just call a function that does this.

but yeah it appear there is no built-in function that does this so I stick with sample.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }

I found this solution but not sure if it is the optimized version
fun main() {
        var sample = "Smooth GPS Readings"
    sample = sample.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }
    println(sample)
}

I have to first convert all to lowercase then modify the first case...
Time complexity (O(n)) is not bad but looking for a case I don't have to convert to lower case

the code you provided converts all the character to lowercase i.e smooth gps readings and then converts the first charater to uppercase i.e Smooth gps readings . The time complexity of lowercase is O(n) where n is total number of character same as for loop.

Now its up to you whether use this method or your own custom logic which will provide you more control over your code since performace of both is same optimization wise.

Time complexity (O(n)) is not bad but looking for a case I don't have to convert to lower case brings you right back to the beginning i guess.

even though your code time complexity is o(n)... it is not optimized compare to mine.
this is 0(n) + 0(n) = 0(n).....

can we have a case to uses only the built in function i.e only 0(n)

cant find an inbuilt sol.

This also doesn't work if the sample string contains multiple sentences. It only makes the first character of the entire string uppercase, not the first character of each sentence, as was requested.

that was the intended question.. if I want first character of each sentence, I could use .capitalizeWords()

Although I do not know what that function is, judging by its name it probably wouldn't work for sentences since it would capitalize each word and not only the first word of a sentence. Doesn't matter though, if this isn't even what you want. Although you did ask for that in your question. It's even in the title.
